# creating a special kind of merged list within a list in django

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm sure that this is pretty easy to do but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have three lists: `list1=[a1, a2, a3...]`, `list2=[b1, b2, b3...]`, and `list3=[c1, c2, c3...]`

I want to pass a list that is a by-item merger of these three:

`finalList = [[a1, b1, c1,], [a2, b2, c2], [a3, b3, c3]...]`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the built-in [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) is for:

```
final_list = zip(list1, list2, list3)
```

Note that `final_list` will actually be a list of tuples, and its length will be the length of the shortest input list.

The functions [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`itertools.izip_longest()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) are also noteworthy.

Comment: ah awesome, thanks. additional q: if I'm going to be iterating through `final_list` in a template, is there an obvious way to do that?